# Wifi very slow on Ubuntu, fast on dual booted windows

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I have a dual boot system (Ubuntu 18.04, Win 10) on which my internet speed is ~70Mbit/s on both Ubuntu and Windows, but after a few minutes it drops to only ~50kbit/s on Ubuntu, making internet basically unusable.

From Ubuntu:

```
$ iwconfig 
wlxe84e06453c21  IEEE 802.11  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:44427   Missed beacon:0
```

which seems to indicate the connection is set up properly at the correct bit rate, but this is not what I get in practice.

For completeness (ethernet connections omitted):

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@3:4
       logical name: wlxe84e06453c21
       serial: e8:4e:06:45:3c:21
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu driverversion=4.15.0-33-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.1.7 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

lsmod output:

```
rtl8xxxu              122880  0
rtl8192cu              73728  0
rtl_usb                20480  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        57344  1 rtl8192cu
rtlwifi                77824  3 rtl_usb,rtl8192c_common,rtl8192cu
mac80211              778240  7 rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rtl_usb,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu,rtl8xxxu
cfg80211              622592  3 rt2x00lib,mac80211,rtlwifi
```

Given that the hardware and router are identical between the Windows and Ubuntu install, I'm left to believe there's a bad Linux driver or config somewhere. Any tips on where to look appreciated.

UPDATE: This is *not* a duplicate of the bug marked by chili555. I don't experience freezing and blacklisting the rtl8192cu driver does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsmod | grep rtl`

Comment: lsmod output added

Comment: @chili555 See edit. Skipping Q in the reopen queue...  **:-)**

Comment: Please show us a new: `lsmod | grep rtl` We wonder where rt2800lib,rt2x00lib, etc. are coming from. They are not, according to modinfo, dependencies of rtl8192cu nor rtl8xxxu.

Comment: `lsmod | grep rtl` looks the same as before. It's possible I have extra modules loaded because I've been using a different wifi dongle so I can get online for more than a few minutes at a time. I'd prefer to use the old dongle since it has an antenna and gets better speed... at least at first.